# What is errno in java

Tags: java, errno

I have an application which simulate Agile scrum board,developed in java which takes commands through command line.For e.g. it takes command like:
"create user story"

One of the rules to develop this application says that:
Your implementation should return a 0 errno on successful completion, 1 for an error

what does this errno means? is errno some specific keyword ?And if its keyword,then how to return this?

I have used system.exit() in below manner. Is it  correct way of using it ? I dont get 0 printed on console when the program is exited?

```
if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")){
        allbacklogs.saveAllUserStory();
        System.exit(0);

    }
```

Thank

Comment: If you examine the description of the tag you added you should find a good enough answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

errno just means error number.

- 0 means that program excecution went fine
- 1 (Or any other integer than 0) means that there was an error

When the program ends naturally, 0 will be returned, and when the program crashes for uncatched exception or error, 1 will be returned automatically.

So you don't actually need to do anything to fit that requirement. If you need to manually use System.exit use System.exit(0) on no error and System.exit(1) on error.

Comment: This is not totally correct. [errno](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cerrno/errno/) is a macro in C++.

Comment: @Turing85 OP's question has the `java` tag though.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, so as per my understanding,this code will return 0 if program ends normally. Is it possible to return errno for each command.i mean when i execute a command,it returns errno 0 if command is successfull

Comment: It's the error number and it's only returned when the program stops running.
In java you don't really use exit codes, so you don't need to do anything.

Comment: Thanks @FINDarkside.. and do we need to define errno somewhere,as when i tried using the above statement,it says errno cannot be resolved. I am using Eclipse for developing the application

Comment: Yes of course, errno is not real variable unless you define it. But as I said, you don't need to declare anything or do anything to fill those requirements.

Comment: @user3300327 I made some changes to the answer, hopefully it's more clear now :)

Comment: @Turing85 - I disagree.  If you try to inject the C / C++ meaning of `errno` in this context, it makes no sense.  The C / C++ macro denotes a value that is returned >>to<< and application by a syscall.  The OP is asking about an "errno" that returned >>by<< the application when it exits.

Comment: I have used system.exit() in below manner. Is it  correct way of using it ? I dont get 0 printed on console when the program is exited?if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")){
   allbacklogs.saveAllUserStory();
   System.exit(0);
   //done=false;
  }

Comment: Yeah, that will work, reaching the end of the main method will do the same thing as System.exit(0). You are doing it correctly even if it is not printed to console (It just means that everything went fine). Try exiting with any other  value and it will be printed to console.

Comment: I tried this,it printed nothing                     if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")){
   allbacklogs.saveAllUserStory();
   System.exit(7);
   //done=false;
  }

Comment: And should not the value of n in  System.exit(n) be set automatically depending upon termination status of program.Why do we need to hardcode it to "0" or 1

Comment: You don't need to hardcode it, you don't even need to use it. Forget the whole errno if you don't use System.exit. And as I said, it is set automatically, but of course it can't be set automatically if you manually shut it down.